# Unable to find file associated with ANT (mac)

Tags: java, macos, bash, ant

I recently installed ANT and I am unable to build due to a file not being found. 
What I have done so far:

1) Installed ANT 1.9.2 via macports
When I type ant into terminal I get an output "Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed". When I type ant -version I get "Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013".
So it looks like ANT is installed.

2) Added paths for ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME in Users/<"myName">/.bash_profile

export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant

export PATH=${PATH}:${ANT_HOME}/bin

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

Did I do this correctly?

Now when I attempt to execute a file (java file with .xml), I get this output:

-bash-3.2$ ant execute
Buildfile: /Users/<"myName">/Desktop/CST420:SER321/Assign0/src/javaFraction/JavaFraction/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/Users/<"myName">/Desktop/CST420:/Users/<"myName">/Desktop/CST420:SER321/Assign0/src/javaFraction/JavaFraction/build.xml:8: The following error occurred while executing this line:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/<"myName">/Desktop/CST420:/usr/local/ant/lib/ant.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:216)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:211)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:176)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:255)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseUnknownElement(ProjectHelper2.java:130)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseAntlibDescriptor(ProjectHelper2.java:110)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Antlib.createAntlib(Antlib.java:91)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.loadAntlib(Definer.java:425)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:277)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.checkNamespace(ComponentHelper.java:874)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.getDefinition(ComponentHelper.java:307)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:284)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:263)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:429)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:163)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:179)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:93)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:826)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 0 seconds

What can I do to remedy this?

Also, I seem to be stuck in the -bash-3.2 shell in my terminal (not sure if this has anything to do with the current issue). Would anyone know how I can get back to the login shell (where is displays the current directory instead of bash)?

Comment: Facing similar issue. Any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the file `/Users/<"myName">/Desktop/CST420:/usr/local/ant/lib/ant.jar` exists.

run this

```
    ls -l  /Users/<"myName">/Desktop/CST420:/usr/local/ant/lib/ant.jar
```

See what happens,

For the second question, try to press `ctrl + d`.

Comment: Here is the URL to a photo of my desktop. It seems that I have the file in the right directory.

http://tinypic.com/r/2e5ld8n/5

When I pressed ctrl + d, all it did was logout and I could no longer type in terminal.